# If $x + \frac{1}{x} = k$, what's the value of this sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Friends, if $x + \frac{1}{x} = k$, with $k$ positive real number, what's the value of
$$1+ x^6 + x^{12} + x^{18} + x^{24}+x^{30}$$

I tried with the substitution $u= x^6$:
$$a= 1+ u + u^2 + u^3 + u^4 + u^5 = \frac{u^6-1}{u-1}$$

and with identities:
$$x + \frac{1}{x} = k \Longrightarrow  x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} = k^2-2$$
$$\left( x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^3 = (k^2-2)^3\Longrightarrow x^6 + 3(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}) + \frac{1}{x^6} = (k^2-2)^3 $$
$$\Longrightarrow x^6 +\frac{1}{x^6} = (k^2-2)^3 - 3(k^2-2).$$

I'm on the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: There is a symmetry in the expression. 
$0 + 30 = 6 + 24 = 12 + 18$...

Comment: @shauryagupta : Good observation... why do you think that would help?

Comment: Well, $x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2+1}{x}$, giving the quadratic equation $x^2+1=kx$. You could solve this for $x$ in terms of $k$ and substitute the result into the partial sum. Is this what you want?

Comment: @solstafir Although that can be done, but I think that since this is a contest-math question, it'll have a more beautiful solution and answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I solved this and got $x^{15}[((k^3-3k) - (k^3 - 3k))][(k^2 - 2)^3 - 3(k^2-2)]$...x^15 seems challenging to solve...Maybe we could multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$.

Comment: @shauryagupta : That seem to be good going.... Good luck!

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** this is the correct problem, if you got it from somewhere?  If you made this question yourself, you should be advised that the answer is extremely complicated for the expression as it is written.

Comment: The initial problem is with $k=3$, but I'm thinking about consequences if $k$ is a real positive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't solved it completely, but still see if the following hint helps you:

HINT:$\large 1+x^6+x^{12}+x^{18}+x^{24}+x^{30}=x^{18}(\frac{1}{x^{18}}+1+(x^{12}+\frac{1}{x^{12}})+(x^{6}+\frac{1}{x^6}))$

$x^{18}(\frac{1}{x^{18}}+1+k^{12}+k^{6}-18*k)$

add and subtract $k^{18}$ inside the bracket to get $x^{18}+\frac{1}{x^{18}}$, we get,

Comment: The x^12 and x^6 terms can be easily solved but x^18 is the main problem...